# ExifTool need to find name of the first file in sequence

Tags: variables, filenames, exiftool

I am using third party image viewer (XnView) that allows to select files i want and then run ExifTool with custom command line on this files only.

When i open multiple files using ExifTool i get name of each file using `${FileName}`.

However i need to find name of only first file from all files selected, because i need to create folder with name of first file in sequence then move all files there.

`-k -Filename<${Directory}\${FileName;s/\.[^.]*$//}\${Filename}` - this moves each file to separate folder, need to move all files to one folder

Is there way to get file names array so i can then query first entry e.g. `filesArray[1]` or how can i get name of first file?

Answer (score 1):

[Related thread on the Exiftool forums](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=13738.0)

Exiftool only processes one file at a time and doesn't have the ability to extract a static value from a list and hold on to that value. You'll have to create a script to find the value you want.

If you're using Linux/Mac, see [command line find first file in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509806/command-line-find-first-file-in-a-directory)
If you're using Windows, maybe [Batch file to list only the first file from every directories in a tree and output the results in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68868393/batch-file-to-list-only-the-first-file-from-every-directories-in-a-tree-and-outp)